# Keras LSTM XOR gate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I was learning about Keras for a project, for trial I try to make a simple machine learning using LSTM (what I will use for the project) for simple XOR gate prediction. But, even though I change number of neuron, layer, loss function, epoch, or optimizer I can't get the correct prediction. Is there something I miss about Keras or this code?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

data = [[[0, 0]], [[0, 1]], [[1, 0]], [[1, 1]]]
output = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1,0]]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(1, 2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(2))

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# print(model.summary())
model.fit(np.asarray(data), np.asarray(output), epochs=50)

print(model.predict_classes(np.asarray(data)))
```

Comment: Works for me by setting epochs=1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are predicting XOR output encoded as one-hot vectors. In this case, it is much like a classification problem. If you use `softmax` to produce a distribution and set your loss to `categorical_crossentropy` your network starts to learn:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

data = [[[0, 0]], [[0, 1]], [[1, 0]], [[1, 1]]]
output = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1,0]]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(1, 2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
# print(model.summary())
model.fit(np.asarray(data), np.asarray(output), epochs=200)

print(model.predict_classes(np.asarray(data)))
```

Also you would need to increase the number of epochs as `adam` default values have small learning rate.